# Openlayers does not print layer from geoserver

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I try to print my geoserver layer on my website. My application and my geoserver instance are running on separate tomcats and use different ports.

I have noticed in my Firefox' network inspector logs that appropriate png images are downloaded from geoserver. I noticed http requests such as:

```
http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=graves:graves&TILED=true&STYLES=graves&CQL_FILTER=not(id < 0)&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG:2001&BBOX=4762.7,-7860.5599999999995,4905.6900000000005,-7717.57
```

and when I use such a link in a browser it gives me a png with some of my elements. However my application does not print any of the elements.

My code is somehow like that:

```
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:2001',
    extent: [4762.7, -8003.55, 4950.55, -7717.57],
    units: 'm'
});
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);

var mapcenter = [4880, -7930];

var mapzoom = 2;

var view = new ol.View({
    center: mapcenter,
    projection: projection,
    zoom: mapzoom
});

var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
  url: 'http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms',
  params: {'LAYERS': 'graves:graves', 'TILED': true, 'STYLES': 'graves' },
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});


var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ 
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: wmsSource
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
        collapsible: false
      })
    }),
    view: view });
```

Of course I have some div as well:

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="width: 1030px; height: 650px;border: 1px solid #0066CC;margin-bottom: 10px;"></div>
```

What may be the cause of this problem? I can see no error on Firefox javascript console. I was totally stuck.

Best Regards

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but you could try to reproject your layer in geoserver to 4326 or 3857 and remove the projection from your openlayers code.

Comment: I did it. And I changed my layer's Declared SRS in my geoserver to EPSG:3857. My Native Bounding Box computed from data are 4,761, -8,004, 4,951, -7,775 however I discovered my application requests BBOX=0,-20037508.342789244,10018754.171394622,-10018754.171394622. I tried to change it by putting extent: [4762.7, -8003.55, 4950.55, -7717.57] in my view but the request did not change.

Comment: I checked that the problem is related to separate tomcats of geoserver application and my own aplication. When I run both of them on a single tomcat instance it seems to be working properly. Unfortunately I cannot run both applications on a single tomcat instance on a production environment.

Comment: did you enable CORS support?

Comment: I added org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter to my tomcat web.xml and set url pattern as /*

Comment: What's especially interesting is that when I use url of one of requests my website and put it as src for img element it prints out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue. The problem was in the line within tileWMS:

```
crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
```

After removing it everything works as expected.
Thank you all for your support!